# GNUCOBOL with embedded sql runtime error : module 'OCESQLConnect' not found

Tags: cygwin, sql

I am currently trying to run a cobol pgm with embedded sql that calls database in postgresql. I am running (GnuCOBOL) 2.2.0 on cygwin.

I have followed steps in https://github.com/opensourcecobol/Open-COBOL-ESQL. I manage to exec all steps. However, when i run the pgm i get OCESQL Connect not found as following : 
$ ./INSERTTBL
*** INSERTTBL STARTED ***
libcob: module 'OCESQLConnect' not found

I suspect it's  libocesql.so not created in /usr/local/lib during 'make install' 
 but I am not sure why it's not created. Hence I can;t add into env >> export COB_PRE_LOAD=/usr/local/lib/libocesql.so . For ld library, i have added under export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 OS:

1. Download esqlOC Component from http://www.kiska.net/opencobol/esql/

   Using the option:
   ESQL Preprocessor and Runtime binaries for Windows x86-64 (AMD-64) andx86
   (win32)

   This link downloads the file BINARIES.ZIP
2. Unzip the BINARIES.ZIP file in the folder where
   theOpenCobolIDE4.7.6

   EX: C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCobolIDE\GnuCOBOL

   The binaries folder containing the esqlOC components is included

[Figure #1 Install binaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI9Ki.png)

3. Include in the SQL COBOL sheet of the “Preferences”
   option in the IDE the new subfolder binaries in esqlOC folder:
   This inclusion is for the pre compiler to work on the program with
   extension".Sqb" (Cobol with SQL statements)

[Figure #2 esqlOC Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A3GR.png)

4. Also include the path to the binaries subfolder in the option
   COMPILER sheet"Preferences" in the IDE. Also include the extension
   ".SQB" in the Associatedextensions of this sheet.

[Figure #3 Compiler Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqTXt.png)

5. Generate a new program cobol with extension .sqb (COBOL WITH EXEC SQL)
6. Include the connection to the Database.

   a. Include the following working fields:

   ```
       EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION END-EXEC.
   01  HOSTVARS.
       05 BUFFER     PIC  X(1024).
       05 hVarD      PIC S9(5)V99.
       05 hVarC      PIC  X(50).
       05 hVarN      PIC 9 (12).

       EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION END-EXEC.
   ```

   b. Include in Procedure Division the following sentences:

*--------------------------------------------------------------------- *

- CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
- also possible with DSN: 'youruser / yourpasswd @ yourODBC_DSN'
  *----------------------------------------------------------------------*

  ```
     STRING 'DRIVER = {MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};'
            'SERVER = localhost;'
            'PORT = 3306;'
            'DATABASE = database;'
            'USER = mysql user;'
            'PASSWORD = mysql password ;'
  ```

*------------------------------------------------- ---------------- *

- example for DB specific ODBC parameter:
- no compressed MySQL connection (would be the DEFAULT anyway)
- ------------------------------------------------- ---------------- *
- ```
            'COMRESSED_PROTO = 0;'
     INTO BUFFER.

     EXEC SQLCONNECT TO: BUFFER
     END-EXEC.
  ```

7. Compile the program that has .SQB extension.
   It will issue the following errors, but it is normal:

   **"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCobolIDE\GnuCOBOL\bin/ld.exe: cannot
   find -locsql.libcollect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status"**
8. Open the cobol program generated by the pre compiler with the .COB
   extension
9. Only compile the program with the .COB extension
   without modifying it.
10. Execute.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You need to download and install Open-COBOL-ESQL-1.2: Open-COBOL-ESQL-1.2.tar.gz

```
$ export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/pgsql/include"
$ export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/pgsql/lib"
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Second: Export these Flags:

```
export COPY=/Users/francisco/Downloads/Open-COBOL-ESQL-1.2/copy
export SCR=/usr/local/share/gnucobol/copy
export OC_OBJ=/Users/francisco/Downloads/Open-COBOL-ESQL-1.2/dblib
```

Third: complile .cbl

```
ocesql random.cbl random.cob
```

Fourth: Make executable

```
cobc -x random.cob $OC_OBJ/ocdb.o $OC_OBJ/ocdblog.o $OC_OBJ/ocdbutil.o $OC_OBJ/ocesql.o $OC_OBJ/ocpgsql.o -I$COPY -I$SCR -locesql -lpq
```

Finally (crossing your fingers):

```
./random
```